# Cypress .each() function only iterating on first instance of element

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm attempting to run through a list of dynamic items on my app. Each item is made up of several displayed elements like name, due date, etc. - These are currently entered by users, so I'm stubbing the data in my test via fixtures to verify they're working as expected.

I'm currently using a .each() loop that references the fixture, referred to as **patientHealthGoals**. Listed below is the relevant portions of the .each() loop.

```
cy.get('userGoalList')
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.get('userGoalItem')
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('[data-cy="due-date"]')
          .should('have.value', userGoals[index].due_at);
        cy.get('[data-cy="comments"]')
          .should('have.value', userGoals[index].comment);
      });
  });
```

What's strange is that, on each iteration, it correctly checks the `[data-cy="due-date"]` field. However, on the `[data-cy="comments"]`, it *always* compares against the first instance of that element, no matter what index it's on. Here is the relevant error I'm getting:

> expected [ < textarea.block.-with-updated.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid.om-input >, 3 more... ] to have value 'Notes for second item', but the value was 'Notes for first item'

The only difference between the `[data-cy="due-date"]` and `[data-cy="comments"]` checks that I can see are the elements themselves. The first one is an `input` and the latter is a `textarea`, but I fail to see why Cypress would be treating them completely differently. Any ideas what might be breaking here?

Comment: I don't know anything about Cypress (never even heard of it before now), but it seems like you should be using `$el` to specify that the selector should be relative to the current item.

Comment: Can you also share the `markup` for `userGoalItem`.